# LiteSpeed vs Apache httpd

Tags: apache, webserver, litespeed

I've been hearing things lately about the [LiteSpeed](http://litespeedtech.com/) webserver as being a drop-in replacement for Apache webserver. Even my web host is going to replace their shared webhost environment with LiteSpeed (I'm currently not sure if I must be happy about that or not).

Does anyone have any experience with the LiteSpeed webserver (both in development and production)? It would be appreciated if you could share your experience here.

Comment: Very constructive. Thanks for asking and answering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should look at those links;

- [LiteSpeed vs Apache (from Litespeed Tech)](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20130307215125/http://www.litespeedtech.com/litespeed-vs-apache.html)
- [Benchmark: LiteSpeed vs Apache (PHP and Plain HTML)](http://www.beyondcoding.com/2008/02/25/benchmark-litespeed-vs-apache-php-and-plain-html/)
- [LiteSpeed vs Apache](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=438134)

Answer (score 4):

Apache can be configured to run as well as Litespeed. Your host is probably taking the lazy way out. There's this benchmark where Apache beats Litespeed (with some help). Check it out: [Apache vs Litespeed](http://www.unixy.net/apache-vs-litespeed/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out benchmarks for litespeed cache vs apache + varnish at http://vbtechsupport.com/26/ there's also static file comparisons between litespeed vs apache vs nginx at http://www.vbulletin.com/forum/entry.php/2452-Boosting-vBulletin-performance-via-caching-Apache-Varnish-versus-Litespeed-Cache